# Datetime parsing error, wrong format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, datetime-format

I'm having some trouble with parsing a datetime string in Python 3.6. The critical code is:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("Jan 08, 2018 07:04 PM UTC", '%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p %Z')
```

And the stacktrace:

```
  File "marquito.py", line 180, in start
    test_date = "" if test_date == "" else datetime.datetime.strptime(test_date + " UTC", "%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p %Z")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Jan 08, 2018 07:04 PM UTC' does not match format '%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p %Z'
```

Do you see anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Same. I can't reproduce this on 3.6.2 either

Comment: are you sure `test_date` variable has the form `"Jan 08, 2018 07:04 PM UTC"` ? print it out to see.

Comment: @ichantz: well, given that the exception message includes exactly that string..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`%b` is *locale dependent*. Your system is set to a locale other than English or C, and thus the month names don't match.

To see the supported month names in your current locale, run:

```
>>> import calendar
>>> print([calendar.month_abbr[i].lower() for i in range(13)])
```

Set your locale back to `C` or English before parsing English month names. You only need to do this for the `LC_TIME` category:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'C')
```

For example, in a spanish locale, your date can't be parsed:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import calendar
>>> with calendar.different_locale('es_ES'):
...     print([calendar.month_abbr[i].lower() for i in range(13)])
...     datetime.datetime.strptime("Jan 08, 2018 07:04 PM UTC", '%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p %Z')
...
['', 'ene', 'feb', 'mar', 'abr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'ago', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dic']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Jan 08, 2018 07:04 PM UTC' does not match format '%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p %Z'
```

but in the default `C` locale parsing succeeds:

```
>>> with calendar.different_locale('C'):
...     print([calendar.month_abbr[i].lower() for i in range(13)])
...     datetime.datetime.strptime("Jan 08, 2018 07:04 PM UTC", '%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p %Z')
...
['', 'jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec']
datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 8, 19, 4)
```

I used the *undocumented, internal* `calendar.different_locale()` context manager to temporarily change the `LC_TIME` locale. It sets the desired locale on entering the context, and on exit it restores the old locale again, using the above `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, ...)` call.

Comment: You are totally correct. PyQt was messing with my locale.
Because of that I wasn't getting that error when testing with the REPL alone.